# Querying and returning Sub Document/Nested Objects in ElasticSearch

Tags: elasticsearch, nest

Good day:

I'm currently have the following structure indexed `school -> children`...meaning for every `school` document, there's a list of `children` sub documents. `Children` is a nested list of objects inside `School`. My objective is to query the parent `school.id=id` and only return the sub-documents matching `children.userId = userId` while paginating the `children` **size/from**. I'm not sure how to accomplish this but, any help using NEST would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT:**

I didn't realize you only wanted to paginate the results from a single document.  In that case you can use `inner_hits` which has it's own `from` and `size` parameters you can use.

Reference: [inner_hits documentation](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-inner-hits.html)

**ORIGINAL ANSWER:**

I don't think you can paginate directly on the inner object when you have a nested type.  Instead you would want to index school and children in separate documents and use a `join` type to create a parent/child relationship between them.  Then you could use a `has_parent` query to search for children and paginate on the children returned.

**Reference:**

How to create the mapping: [Join Relationship](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/parent-join.html)

How to create the query: [has_parent query](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/query-dsl-has-parent-query.html)

Comment: Not totally understanding this. If I'm only doing paginating on sub documents on only ONE PARENT (never multiple parents..only one single parent) surely shouldn't this be possible with ES?

Comment: Sorry, didn't understand you only cared about one parent at a time.  Updated my answer.